# result format from a Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm having problems with autocomplete and jquery.
A web page return the following array:

```
[{'id':'test','value':'test'},{'id':'test','value':'test2'}]
```

the page with the jquery code includes the following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="field" />

<script>
$(function() {


$("#field").autocomplete({source: "http://localhost/richieste/mypage.asp"});


 });
 </script>
```

Is there anything wrong in the array maybe?

**EDIT:** contrary to what I wrote, the page is not called on the server. I've tried both

```
    $("#field").autocomplete({source: "http://localhost/richieste/mypage.asp"});
```

and

```
    $("#field").autocomplete({source: "mypage.asp"});
```

Thanks

Comment: The response should have `label` properties, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: I think you should provide different id for each element. The value that is displayed in .autocomplete is the label one (id in this case)

Answer (score 0):

use different ids, try doing:

```
$("#field").autocomplete({
    source: "http://localhost/richieste/mypage.asp"
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = (function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.value + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfBNh/1/)